# Show posts from custom post type sorted by category/taxonomy on a one-pager/page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pages

I'm working on a one-pager wp site for a festival (page: Home). This festival has 4 stages. I created a custom post type "artists" with  custom taxonomy "stages" and entered the 4 names of the stages. ([screenshot](https://cl.ly/7498ad92507e)). I've added all artists and assigned them to a stage.

How can I show on my page an overview of stages with their artists?

Stage1:
-Artist1
-Artist 2

Stage2:
-Artist3
-Artist4

And so on ...

I've managed to show all artists but I can't figure out how to sort them by stage. I've tried hundreds of things without luck. This is my code so far ..

```
<?php 
            query_posts(array( 
                'post_type' => 'artists',
                'showposts' => -1,
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'nopaging' => true,
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
                'terms' => array(7, 10),//stage1&2
            ) );  
        ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_field('artist_external_link'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a>     
        <?php endwhile;?>
```

I appreaciate the help!

Comment: Get all taxonomy terms (stages), then get posts (artists) for each term (stage).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Max, this pointed me in the right direction. I found some code that worked and adapted this to my needs. It works like a charm but the only thing that still bothers me is that I can not change the order in which the stages appear. Order is probably defined by what "stage" added first to wordpress.

```
<?php 
            $terms_array = array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'stages', // you can change it according to your taxonomy
            'parent'   => 0 // If parent => 0 is passed, only top-level terms will be returned
            );
            $stages_terms = get_terms($terms_array); 
            foreach($stages_terms as $stage): ?>
            <div class="room">
                <h4><?php echo $stage->name; ?></h4>
            <?php 
            $post_args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'artists', // you can change it according to your custom post type
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'stages', // you can change it according to your taxonomy
                        'field' => 'term_id', // this can be 'term_id', 'slug' & 'name'
                        'terms' => $stage->term_id,
                    )
                )
            );
            $myposts = get_posts($post_args); ?>
            <ul>
            <?php foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_field('artist_external_link'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a>     
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; // Term Post foreach ?>
            </ul></div>
            <!-- end room -->   
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            <?php endforeach; // End Term foreach; ?>
```